# Написал код php и есть вопрос про его работоспособность

Tags: php, html

Я написал код на задачу которая звучит так (Создание сокращенного варианта ФИО. Вводим через форму: Иванов
Иван Петрович и нам выводит в строку: Иванов И. П.) Но в выводе в итоге ничего не выдает, в чем тут ошибка? При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит и не выводится

```html
<?php 
$lastName = $_POST["$lastName"];
$name = $_POST["$name"];
$secondName = $_POST["$secondName"];
?>

<html lang="ru">
<title>prak</title>
<body>
    <h2> Создание скоращенного варианта ФИО </h2>
    <form action="5.php" mathod="post">
        <label>
            <input name="$lastName" type="text" placeholder="Фамилия">
            <input name="$name" type="text" placeholder="Имя">
            <input name="$secondName" type="text" placeholder="Отчество">
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </label>
    </form>
</body>

<?php
echo $lastName . " " . mb_substr($name, 0, 1) . "." . mb_substr($secondName, 0, 1) . ". ";
?>
</html>
```

Comment: а куда вы хотите вывести - у вас body уже закрыт перед echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написано

```
mathod
```

должно быть

```
method
```

А раз это некорректно, то по умолчанию данные отсылаются через GET

---

Также надо выводить данные **до**  закрытия тега `</body>`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, но еще я убрал двойные кавычки, они тоже не давали вывести

Comment: Вроде двойные кавычки не причём

Comment: пока они стояли ничего не выводилось, я заменил их на одинарные и все вывелось

Comment: ааа...я понял про какие идёт речь... да... там где `POST[...]` надо... потому что в ином случае в строке парсились переменные, которые начинаются со знака доллара. Но я бы рекомендовал в HTML давать имена без знака доллара.  Так больше принято. Тогда и в `POST[...]` всё ок будет всегда